# Python3 - How can I make a spinner that will display for 8 seconds

Tags: time, while-loop, python-3.8

I am new to Python so please be nice.

I want to make a spinner cursor using a while loop that will display for 8 seconds.

```py
spinner = [ '-', '\\', '|', '/' ]
for i in spinner:
   while i < 8:
       print("looking for coupons",spinner[i % len(spinner)]))
```

Ok, so what am trying to do here is to make a loading spinning cursor that spins at the end of "looking for coupons". sorta like a loading bar.

Answer (score 0):

i try this but i didn't get exactly what you asked

```py
import time
import sys
second = 0  
def spin():
        while True:
            for cursor in '|/-\\':
                yield cursor
spinner=spin()  
while True:
    time.sleep(1)    
    second+=1
    if True:
        sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\b')
    if second==8:
        break
```

iam trying, if i get the answer i will post.

Comment: are you satisfy with this code, if not please comment.